# Abstract Algebra group order

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

let $g$ be in $G$ of order $n$. Suppose that $n=kd$. Prove the element $g^d$ has order $k$. am trying to prove this problem and have no idea where to start.

Comment: Do you know what it means for $g$ to have order $n$?

Comment: We call n the order of g if g^n=e where e is the identity element

Comment: So is $2n$ also the order of $g$? If $g^n=e$, then certainly $g^{2n}=(g^n)^2=e^2=e$.

Comment: hmmm. So would doing something like g^n = g^kd = (g^d)^k = e^k help me?

Comment: Yes, it would! Although you need to double check the definition of "order". There is an extra requirement that you are missing.

Answer (score 1):

First $g^n=g^{dk}=(g^d)^k$ so the order $|g^d| \leq k$. However if $|g^d| < k$ then there exists some $q < k$ such that $(g^d)^q=g^{dq}=e$ contradicting that $|g|=n$ so it $|g^d|=k$ as desired.